# scheme list equivalence comparison

Tags: list, comparison, lisp, scheme

Hello I need to check if two lists have same elements in same order but I wasn't able to achieve as it seems like scheme eq? and eqv? checks by reference so giving false to such:

```
> (eq? (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3))
#f
> (eqv? (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3))
#f
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This [site](http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.2/doc/mit-scheme-ref/Equivalence-Predicates.html) explains the difference between those operators. But essentially, you want to use `equal?` when you want to compare the contents of two objects.

Answer (score 12):

seems like equal? and eq? are seperate procedures where equal checks as I needed:

```
> (equal? (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2 3))
#t
```